# Flutter in an existing project

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I have integrated a flutter module into an existing native project (iOS / Android).

I want to attach the debugger or the console log to the flutter module when running the native project.

I don't know how or even if it is possible.
To replace this inconvenience so far I have used the hot reload feature and made some additional workarounds for it (I have a text widget to display my prints).

Comment: As per mine, it's not possible because of android/IOS native not able to read/use the file from the dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `print()` in your `flutter` to add the logs. if you do any changes first run flutter module then run Android/ios. in the `logcat` if you search for flutter you will get flutter module logs

Comment: print statements from flutter appear in the console of xcode as well as android studio but you cannot attach flutter to existing process. though it would be a nice addition in the future.